# Upload forum results to file

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post">
  Username: <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
  Password: <input name="password" type="text" /><br />
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

When someone fills out the form above, is it possible for the results to be uploaded to a text file, such as results.txt, rather than being emailed?

So for example, if the site link was hithere.com, the results would be uploaded to a password-protected text file at hithere.com/results.txt.

Thanks!

Comment: it is entirely possible. Just treat it as an uploaded file or write to file. Many ways to do this.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could provide me with a solution answer with the code, as I'm not experienced in this area.

Comment: well that "answer" below (edit: *now deleted*), has code alright... .in the "link" they provided, which by Stack's standards, link-only answers are highly not accepted.

Comment: As I mentioned, I looked at that URL, but it seems to complex, which is why I posted this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can find documentation on how to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp).

Please, next time search the internet before asking a question.

Comment: Give me a few minutes i will write a start for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a posible code to be executed from your .php form handler file

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("result.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $text = $_POST['username']."\n";
  $text .= $_POST['password']."\n";
  $text .= $_POST['email']."\n";
  $text .= $_POST['subject']."\n\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $text);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Also, you may need to add an `action` attribute to your form tag, whose value should be the same as the .php filename(or route if it is not in the same folder). For example if your php file is `form_handler.php` you should have `<form method='post' action='form_handler.php'>`

A little bit explaining on the php code above, you open the file with the second parameter `"a"` to tell the server you don't want to override the file's content but just add some content after the existing one(append). If you wanted to override the contetn that parameter should be `"w"` Then you set all the text in a variable, and write it in the file with `fwrite()`. After this you need to close the file with `fclose()`

Edit: In case you don't know, `"\n"` are linebreaks.

Comment: It seems that when I open result.txt, it's blank

Comment: @JugglingBob I'm sorry, it is `fwrite($myfile, $text);`, not `$txt`. Edited